# Getting 'The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values' with MEAN and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, mean-stack, reverse-proxy

I have developed an application in MEAN stack and used Nginx for HTTPS.
I have used socket.io and developed rest apis in node.

Below is my Nginx configuration;

```
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.some.com www.api.some.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.some.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.some.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {    
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,from,x-auth,Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;

    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,from,x-auth,Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,from,x-auth,Access-Control-Allow-Origin';

    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';   
  }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,from,x-auth';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,from,x-auth';

    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';    
 }


        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    ##### changes for socket.io 
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }

}
```

I am getting "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values" error when my application is attempting to connect socket.

I have found a workout. If I comment the 'add_header' part from the GET section and add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header from my code then it is working fine. If I don't add the header in my code then the GET rest apis are not working , its asking for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

But I don't want to do that as nginx should handle this, my code should not bother about these headers.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE :**

I added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in allow headers part of the GET in nginx and removed the GET specific code from node server , the get rest APIs started working BUT the socket started throwing CORS origin error.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm also getting the same error on SocketIO and can't fix it.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi Nope for 'GET', but for websockets you need to add '    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";' as websockets change the http protocol to websockets by header upgrade